# How to find this LEGO part name? For connection of Technic bricks and steering liftarms

Tags: part-identification, technic

I have checked Bricklink for Lego Technic but still can't find it's name.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [part# 32069 or 64920: Technic, Steering Arm with Pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32069#T=C).

[image]

Found by looking at the (relatively short) list of parts in Bricklink's inventory under the [Technic, Steering](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=141) category.

Comment: Thank you a lot!